# Getting all lines between two lines in separate groups

Tags: .net, regex

I am pretty new to regular expressions, and I have encountered a problem. I have the following data in the middle of a string with a lot of newlines:

```
Data I dont care about
Start row
First data row
Second data row
Third data row
End row
More data I dont care about
```

I need to write a regular expression that will create three groups with the data rows. I have tried writing

```
(?<=Start row\n)(.|\n)+?(?=End row)
```

But this only gives me one group containing all three data rows, instead of three groups with one row in each. It is also possible that there might exist 4 or 5 data rows that I'd like to get in separate groups, if possible. The content in the data rows does not follow a specific pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then fetch  three separate rows from group index 1.

```
@"(?s)(?:(?<=Start row\n)|(?<!^)\G)\n?([^\n]+)(?=.*?End row)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sR4dP6/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the *Capture Collections* class.
Just match with this, then iterate over group 1.

`@"Start[ ]row\r?\n(?:([^\r\n]*)\r?\n)+?End[ ]row"`

```
 Start [ ] row
 \r? \n 
 (?:
      ( [^\r\n]* )                  # (1)
      \r? \n 
 )+?
 End [ ] row
```

C# code:

```
string strSrc =
    "Data I dont care about\n" +
    "Start row\n" +
    "First data row\n" +
    "Second data row\n" +
    "Third data row\n" +
    "End row\n" +
    "More data I dont care about\n" +
    "End row\n";

Regex rx = new Regex(@"Start[ ]row\r?\n(?:([^\r\n]*)\r?\n)+?End[ ]row");
Match srcMatch = rx.Match(strSrc);
if (srcMatch.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection cc = srcMatch.Groups[1].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = '{1}'", i, cc[i].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
0 = 'First data row'
1 = 'Second data row'
2 = 'Third data row'
```